# Route Guard Doesn't work on first attempt with React and Amplify

Tags: reactjs, typescript, navigation, aws-amplify

I have set up a route guard with my React/Ionic app and don't want any of the routes to be accessible if there is no logged in user. However, the async seems to be working improperly because it doesn't navigate the user to the new route when they first try to log in, like the function returns before login is evaluated. When you click a second time, it seems to work, and navigates properly. How can I correct this?

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, restricted, ...rest }: any) => {
  const [userInfo, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const isAuthenticated = () => {
    Auth.currentSession()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.isValid()) {
          setAuth(true);
        } else {
          setAuth(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    isAuthenticated();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        userInfo ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Here is how I use the Private Route

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
<PrivateRoute path="/verification" component={MainNavigtion} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial value for `userInfo` is false, so it will instantly redirect to `/login`.

Try setting `userInfo` default value to `null`

`const [userInfo, setAuth] = useState(null);`

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) =>
    userInfo === null ? <p>loading</p> : userInfo 
      ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />   
  }
/>
```

---

I would recommend wrapping your Route component with Loader component so that when the `userInfo` is null it will show Loader.

```
return (
    <Loader loading={userInfo===null}>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          userInfo ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
      />
    </Loader>
  );
```